# Angular2+ Cucumber & Protractor intercept http calls

Tags: angular, testing, protractor, cucumber, nock

I am trying to intercept http requests that my Angular2+ application makes in my cucumber tests. I tried using `nock` without success. I don't believe nock is intercepting my http calls. What am I missing from the below code?

I have a service class that makes my REST calls:

```
@Injectable()
export class RestService {

    getTestdata() {
        this.http.get<ITestData>('/info/testdata', { observe: 'response' })
            .catch(this.handleError)
            .subscribe(response => this._testData.next({ ...response.body }));
    }

}
```

In my cucumber test file, I do:

```
import { browser, element, by, protractor } from 'protractor';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import * as testData from '../../utilities/data/testData.json';

const { Before, After, Given, When, Then, defineSupportCode } = require('cucumber');
const chai = require('chai').use(require('chai-as-promised'));
const expect = chai.expect;
const nock = require('nock');

defineSupportCode(function ({ setDefaultTimeout }) {
    setDefaultTimeout(120 * 1000);
});

Before(() => {
    nock('http://localhost:9084').log(console.log).get('/info/testdata').reply(200, of(testdata));
});

After(() => {
    nock.cleanAll();
});

Given('something', (next: any) => {
    next();
});

When('the user loads the page', (next: any) => {
    testData['testKey1'] = false;
    testData['testKey2'] = false;

    browser.get('/').then(next());
});

Then('element is { displayed } to the user', (displayed: boolean, next: any) => {
    const testElement = element(by.id('test-element'));

    testElement .isPresent().then(response => {
        expect(response).to.equal(displayed);
        next();
    });
});
```

As soon as the page loads using `browser.get('/')`, my components make a call to the given endpoint. I believe the call is not being intercepted because the `testData` object never has its keys changed (I change the values in the `When` step. I also did a `console.log` and it is always the original values, never `false`).

Also, the `.log(console.log)` doesn't do anything. I never see anything printed anywhere. What am I doing wrong?

Is there something else I can use? Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Did you get any solution on this ?

Comment: syy: Please post your findings

Comment: Sorry, I never found a solution to this.

Comment: `nock` is a node (server-side) http mocking library. I don't think it would be able to override the Angular (client-side) http calls.